# Embedding Code into my site

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty basic site constructed using simple HTML and CSS code. I was looking for a way to embed code for the purposes of creating a tutorial and came across http://hilite.me/. It worked great with the Java code I put into it but the end result came out to be looking like this:

[image]

Here is the code in question:

```
<div style="background: #ffffff; overflow:auto;width:auto;border:solid gray;border-width:.1em .1em .1em .8em;padding:.2em .6em;"><table><tr><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%"> 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18</pre></td><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%"><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">import</span> <span style="color: #0e84b5; font-weight: bold">org.openqa.selenium.By</span><span style="color: #333333">;</span>
<span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">import</span> <span style="color: #0e84b5; font-weight: bold">org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver</span><span style="color: #333333">;</span>
<span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">import</span> <span style="color: #0e84b5; font-weight: bold">org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver</span><span style="color: #333333">;</span>

<span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">public</span> <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">class</span> <span style="color: #BB0066; font-weight: bold">WebDriverTest</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>

<span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">public</span> <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">static</span> <span style="color: #333399; font-weight: bold">void</span> <span style="color: #0066BB; font-weight: bold">main</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span>String<span style="color: #333333">[]</span> args<span style="color: #333333">)</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>

    WebDriver driver <span style="color: #333333">=</span> <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">new</span> FirefoxDriver<span style="color: #333333">();</span>

    driver<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">get</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span><span style="background-color: #fff0f0">&quot;http://www.cnbc.com&quot;</span><span style="color: #333333">);</span>

    System<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">out</span><span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">println</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span>driver<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">getTitle</span><span style="color: #333333">());</span>

    driver<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">close</span><span style="color: #333333">();</span>

<span style="color: #333333">}</span>
<span style="color: #333333">}</span>
</pre></td></tr></table></div>
```

How do I change it so that the 'box' around the code fits as wide as the code itself?

Comment: To clarify, you want the gray background expanded to fit the whole width of the box, or you want the width of the box to shrink to only be as wide as needed for the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `<div>` elements have block display, which, by default, has 100% width. There are two easy ways to fix this:

### 1. Use Inline-Block Display:

You can set your div to use inline-block display so that it has automatic width:

```
div#myDiv{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jENs/)

---

### 2: Set the width.

If you know the exact width of the content, you can set the width directly:

```
div#myDiv{
    width: 400px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jENs/1/)

Comment: This worked beautifully. I know I am being greedy here but is there a way to make the top & bottom padding equal to the left & right padding? It looks very uneven and distracting right now. http://www.screencast.com/t/SUn4gzIm